# Key repeat does not work after last OS update

Tags: updates, keyboard, input

As the title says, keyboard repeat stopped working. I mean the behavior which causes repeating key presses when holding a button. For example holding the right arrow should move my cursor between words, but it does not. Holding an 'f' button does not type in 'fffffff' in any application at all. It does not work anywhere. Keyboard settings seem to be configured properly in the `switchboard`.

**EDIT:** I discovered using `xev` that my [system](/questions/tagged/system) is registering key presses constantly, even when I am not pressing anything. `xev` returns the following:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0x2c8, subw 0x0, time 161832, (322,168), root:(1193,635),
state 0x0, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This event keeps popping up constantly, again, without pressing anything.

Any clue on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be caused by a bug in the kernel module `peaq_wmi` as unloading it fixes the issue. This bug was intruced by the 4.13 kernel update. More people have had it. More info here: [Arch linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230340), and the solution is here: [unix & linux autorepeat does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395535/autorepeat-does-not-work/416363#416363).

It seems that updating the linux kernel of elementaryOS will be mandatory once again (once the issue is resolved), in order to solve the issue for people incapable of fixing this issue.

Note: I am on Lenovo Yoga 500-14IHW